# Getting AttributeError after defining object

Tags: python, class, object

I am very new to programming and just tried to define my first object in `Python` using `class` keyword. I am getting error which I don't fully understand. Can someone please correct me? My code is below:

```
class Circle:
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.radius = radius
        self.area=radius*radius*Circle.pi
        self.circum = radius * Circle.pi * 2

c = Circle
print('Radius is:',c.radius)
print('Area is  :',c.area)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
print('Radius is:',c.radius)
AttributeError: type object 'Circle' has no attribute 'radius'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using `PyCharm` to run this code. When I run the same code in `Jupyter` notebook I don't get any errors. Why is that?

Comment: You're not creating an instance of the class. Use `c = Circle()` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance, change your line number 9 to below (missing paranthesis)

```
c = Circle()
```